# Clang does not work properly with std::experimental::optional

Tags: c++, macos, clang, c++14, option-type

It seems that *clang* does not work properly with `std::experimental::optional`.
Consider the following example:

```
#include <experimental/optional>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo { int bar; };

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    std::experimental::optional<Foo> opt = foo;
    opt.value().bar = 42;
    std::cout << opt.value().bar << std::endl;
}
```

It compiles fine with g++ version 5.3.1, but it doesn't neither with clang version 7.0.0 nor with clang version 7.0.2.
The returned error is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"std::experimental::bad_optional_access::~bad_optional_access()", referenced from:
    _main in main-11b2dd.o
"typeinfo for std::experimental::bad_optional_access", referenced from:
    _main in main-11b2dd.o
"vtable for std::experimental::bad_optional_access", referenced from:
    std::experimental::bad_optional_access::bad_optional_access() in main-11b2dd.o
NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I didn't manage to find any issue opened in the bug report for clang.
Who is behaving properly? I guess g++ works fine, while clang seems to be bugged. Am I wrong?

**EDIT1**

Actually, the bug seems to be due to the definition of `bad_optional_access`, even though the problem happens while using clang.

**EDIT2**

No command line parameters, but `-std=c++14`.
Tests performed with clang on osx, it compiles fine (so `optional` is freely available) as far as you don't use the `value` member method.
That means that it compiles and links using:

```
opt->bar
```

Instead of:

```
opt.value().bar
```

Comment: Which implementation of `optional` are you using? Is it [`libstdc++`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html) or the [`libc++`](http://libcxx.llvm.org/ts1z_status.html) version?

Comment: @NicolBolas libstdc++ with g++, libc++ with clang.

Comment: Works fine for me (linux, clang 3.5 or 3.7, libc++ 3.5). You forgot to show the command line.

Comment: Quite easy: `-std=c++14` and that's all. Note that the clang version is far newer (7.*).

Comment: clang 7 sounds suspiciously like running on OSX, which means there's a good chance that apple's just not exposing `std::experimental` in the `libc++` that they ship (this is just a suspicion, though)

Comment: @Petesh of course, running on osx, but it works fine as far as you don't use the `value` method.

Comment: A quick glance at the header tells us why you're having a linking issue - `bad_optional_access` is used if you call `value()`. There's a virtual destructor in the `bad_optional_access` class, which means implementation is needed, as well as the vtable. There are no exported `experimental` symbols in `/usr/lib/libc++.dylib`. I'm going to go with this is an apple decision to not put `experimental` code into their shipped *on the operating system* libc++ because it would constitute a contract to continue supplying it for ABI reasons.

Comment: @Petesh Well, but it doesn't make sense. As far as you don't use `value`, `experimental::optional` is freely available and we are actually using it with no problems in a company's project. So, it looks much more like a bug, doesn't it? We have already looked over the implementation and we found almost the same.

Comment: Based on the libc++ source, it looks like someone would have had to have gone to at least some effort to remove the symbols from the library, which to me, sounds like an active decision being made, but if you feel it's a bug then you can always file a radar with apple. If you want to work around it, you can always put in a `std::experimental::bad_optional_access::~bad_optional_access() _NOEXCEPT = default;`

Comment: @skypjack version 7.* is not "far newer", it is Apple's marketing department renumbering versions to confuse their users.

Comment: @Marc Glisse I can't say you are wrong, indeed. My mistake. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks perfectly fine, `opt.value()` should return a reference to the contained value assuming it is engaged or throw an exception. We can look at one of the [older proposals](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3672.html) which has more examples than the later ones and it includes the following paragraph:

> Using the indirection operator for a disengaged object is an undefined behavior. This behavior offers maximum runtime performance. In addition to indirection operator, **we provide member function value that returns a reference to to the contained value if one exists or throws an exception (derived from logic_error) otherwise**

and if look at the [latest proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3793.html) it describes `value()` as:

> ```
> constexpr T const& optional<T>::value() const;
> T& optional<T>::value();
> ```
>
> Returns:
>
> `*val`, if `bool(*this)`.
>
> Throws:
>
> `bad_optional_access` if `!*this`.
>
> Remarks:
>
> The first function shall be a `constexpr` function.

and provides a sample implementation of `value`:

```
constexpr T const& value()
{
    return *this ? storage_.value_ : (throw bad_optional_access(""), storage_.value_);
}
```

In your case `opt` is engaged and if it was not it should just throw, we would not be invoking undefined behavior.

Note, this compiles on the last several versions of clang on Wandbox(*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/7iYxLIfvXQMFjSCP)*).

So as Petesh suggests this could be intentional on your platform but the only way to confirm that would be to file a bug report.

Also note as the proposal notes there is also a [reference implementation on github](https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional/) which may be a short-term option.

Comment: I like githug. So much better than github.

Comment: @T.C. githug was lovely indeed!! :-D

Comment: Honestly, I don't get the intention. It would have made sense to forbid the use of `optional`. Does it make sense to let the clients use it, the whole class, but for the `value` member method? It sounds like a bug. Have I missed something? Anyway, upvoted. :-)

Comment: @skypjack I don't see an obvious flaw in Petesh's reasoning. As to why, I don't know. I would assume it is a bug, file a bug report and see what the response is.

Comment: Absolutely, do not misunderstand, no flaws at all in all your reasonings. I'm just curious to understand if it sounds weird only to me. :-) ... Do you suggest to fill a bug report to `clang` or to `libc++`? The second maybe is more appropriate.

Comment: No, the bug report should be to macosx.

Comment: Never opened a bug report to macosx, but I'd be glad to do that as an older Debian user. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:**

@Petesh's solution in the comments solved the issue for me (occurred with Clang 4.0.0 built from source on OSX), namely to add a default  implementation (`= default`) in .../experimental/optional:
`std::experimental::bad_optional_access::~bad_optional_access‌​() _NOEXCEPT = default;`.

**Details:**

Using the dereference operator as per @Shafik's answer did not work as expected, because the current implementation supplies `(void)0` as a value when a disengaged optional is dereferenced.  This yields a 0 for optional for example--which is incorrect behavior.  (I also don't feel that the (dis)engagement check should be implemented as an assert, because the assert is likely to be compiled out in release builds, which is unexpected.)

To fix the `(void)0` problem, `_LIBCPP_ASSERT` must be defined with proper behavior--if `_LIBCPP_DEBUG_LEVEL` to be defined to be at least 1, then `_LIBCPP_ASSERT` will be defined as `((x) ? (void)0 : (_VSTD::fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", m), _VSTD::abort()))`, which should yield expected behavior.

But the problem is, according to the [libc++ docs](http://libcxx.llvm.org/debug_mode.html), `_LIBCPP_DEBUG_LEVEL` is a work in progress, and defining it will yield "fairly nasty compile errors".  Well, I tried it, and they did not lie. :(